# What is the purpose of `binding` from `VkVertexInputBindingDescription`?

Tags: c++, vulkan

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkVertexInputBindingDescription.html

> - binding is the binding number that this structure describes.

I am not sure what this means for example from https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/triangle/triangle.cpp

```
    #define VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID 0
    ....
    vertices.inputAttributes[0].binding = VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID;
    vertices.inputAttributes[0].location = 0;
    vertices.inputAttributes[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    vertices.inputAttributes[0].offset = offsetof(Vertex, position);
    // Attribute location 1: Color
    vertices.inputAttributes[1].binding = VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID;
    vertices.inputAttributes[1].location = 1;
    vertices.inputAttributes[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
    vertices.inputAttributes[1].offset = offsetof(Vertex, color);
```

and the vertex shader looks like this

```
#version 450

#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

layout (binding = 0) uniform UBO 
{
    mat4 projectionMatrix;
    mat4 modelMatrix;
    mat4 viewMatrix;
} ubo;

layout (location = 0) out vec3 outColor;

out gl_PerVertex 
{
    vec4 gl_Position;   
};


void main() 
{
    outColor = inColor;
    gl_Position = ubo.projectionMatrix * ubo.viewMatrix * ubo.modelMatrix * vec4(inPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Why is the `binding` 0? When will it have a different value than 0? What is the purpose of `binding`?

My first idea was that it might have been a special qualifier in glsl https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points .

But this doesn't seem to work for the vertex input qualifiers.

Update:

I think I have figured out what the purpose of binding is

```
void vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(
    VkCommandBuffer                             commandBuffer,
    uint32_t                                    firstBinding,
    uint32_t                                    bindingCount,
    const VkBuffer*                             pBuffers,
    const VkDeviceSize*                         pOffsets);
```

I assume that you can have a pipeline with some backed state but it can still change the vertex input layout so that you can have different shaders per pipeline.

And then the `binding` is just a unique identifier to change the vertex layout "on the fly".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I think I have figured out what the purpose of binding is

No, you haven't, but you are close to it.

The buffer binding has the same meaning as it does when using [separate attribute formats](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format) in OpenGL. There are attribute locations and there are buffer binding indices. Each attribute location has a format and offset that defines how to interpret its data. But it also has to have a way to say which buffer it uses.

In Vulkan, attributes and their formats are *immutable* for a particular pipeline. Attribute formats for a pipeline are established at creation time and cannot be changed. However, the *buffers* those attributes pull from are mutable state. They are not fixed at pipeline creation time.

`binding` is an index into the `pBuffers` array bound by `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers`. Each vertex attribute has a `binding` that says which buffer binding index the attribute gets its data from. But the buffer *itself* is not specified at creation time. You set it dynamically with `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers`.

So the `binding` value for an attribute is [equivalent to the `binding` value you provide to `glVertexAttribBinding`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972230/734069)

Comment: so is it intended to use the same`VkBuffer` multiple times with different offsets if the vertex data is not interleaved in the `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers` call? Thanks.

Comment: @ale64bit: If your vertex data is not interleaved but does live in the same `VkBuffer`, then yes, that buffer will appear multiple times in your `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers` call.