# ARB_vertex_attrib_binding test case understanding

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am investigating OpenGL Android deqp test suit and confused with one of the cases. Test is ***dEQP-GLES31.functional.vertex_attribute_binding.usage.mixed_usage.mixed_api_change_binding_point***.
Sources can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/deqp/+/deqp-dev/modules/gles31/functional/es31fVertexAttributeBindingTests.cpp), lines of interest is 1197-1213. I have no idea, that a trick is used.

```
        const int maxUsedLocation   = de::max(positionLoc, colorLoc);
        const int bindingPoint1     = maxUsedLocation + 1;
        const int bindingPoint2     = maxUsedLocation + 2;
        // bind data using old api
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(bindingPoint1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (glw::GLsizei)(2 * sizeof(tcu::Vec4)), (const deUint8*)DE_NULL);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(bindingPoint2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (glw::GLsizei)(2 * sizeof(tcu::Vec4)), (const deUint8*)DE_NULL + sizeof(tcu::Vec4));
        // change buffer binding point with vertex_attrib_binding
        gl.glVertexAttribFormat(positionLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
        gl.glVertexAttribFormat(colorLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
        gl.glVertexAttribBinding(positionLoc, bindingPoint1);
        gl.glVertexAttribBinding(colorLoc, bindingPoint2);
```

First of all, `bindingPoint1` and `bindingPoint2` was initialized in a strange way (increment of max number vertex locations in shader). Then it was used as vertex attrib location(?) in `glVertexAttribPointer`. After that it used as vertex buffer binding point in `glVertexAttribBinding`. And finally, there are no `glBindVertexBuffer` call, which buffer `bindingPoint1` and `bindingPoint2` was bound to?  I try to understand **ARB_vertex_attrib_binding extension**, but I still don't understand this code.

For me it seems that `glVertexAttribPointer` is incorrect because of incorrect vertex attrib locations and `glVertexAttribBinding` is incorrect too, because no vertex binding point bound to vertex buffer.
Can someone explain me, that is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are reading is a test, used to verify that an OpenGL driver has implemented the functionality correctly. It is *not meant* to be an example of reasonable code. It's basically testing a corner case, one that sane code would generally never trigger.

Vertex attrib binding effectively redefined the meaning of `glVertexAttribPointer`, [specifying that it now works by using `glVertexAttribFormat`/etc internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972230/734069). This test is intended to verify that the driver is implementing the redefined `glVertexAttribPointer` correctly.

Again, you shouldn't write code that mixes the two like this. But the specification allows it, so a good tester should verify that the implementation is doing its job.

So the two calls to `glVertexAttribPointer` effectively do the following:

```
glVertexAttribFormat(bindingPoint1, ..., 0);
glBindVertexBuffer(bindingPoint1, m_buffer, 0, (glw::GLsizei)(2 * sizeof(tcu::Vec4)));
glVertexAttribBinding(bindingPoint1, bindingPoint1);

glVertexAttribFormat(bindingPoint2, ..., 0);
glBindVertexBuffer(bindingPoint2, m_buffer, sizeof(tcu::Vec4), (glw::GLsizei)(2 * sizeof(tcu::Vec4)));
glVertexAttribBinding(bindingPoint2, bindingPoint2);
```

So this sets up two attributes as well as two buffer bindings. But the shader never actually uses these attributes.

The later code sets up two more attributes, but this:

```
    gl.glVertexAttribBinding(positionLoc, bindingPoint1);
    gl.glVertexAttribBinding(colorLoc, bindingPoint2);
```

Means that they get the attributes get their vertex data from the previously established binding points. So the two attributes the VS actually *uses* get their buffer data from the buffer binding points `bindingPoint1` and `bindingPoint2`. The other two attributes, which also get their data from the same binding points, are not used by the VS and therefore are irrelevant.

And now let me re-reemphasize that in real code, you should *never do this*. Pick an API style and stick with it. Or failing that, pick an API style within the same VAO.