# What exactly are D3D Input Slots and what is the OpenGL equivalent?

Tags: opengl, direct3d

In Direct3D, when we specify the input to vertex shader using `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` and when we call `IASetVertexBuffers`, we have to specify 'the input slot(s)'. What exactly are these input slots, and what is the OpenGL equivalent? These input slots don't seem to be the same thing as 'locations' specified via `layout(location = K)` in GLSL and the first argument to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vertex input comes from an array of values stored in a buffer. The `SemanticIndex` identifies where that input goes in the shader. The `InputSlot` defines which *buffer* provides the data for that attribute. Buffers aren't bound to semantic indices; they're bound to input slots.

See, D3D has two arrays of things: an array of semantics (which match semantics defined in the shader) and an array of input slots. Each semantic you use has an INPUT_DESC structure for it, which specifies (among other things) the mapping from a semantic to the input slots that feeds it. Vertex buffers are bound to input slots. Any inputs which use those slots will pull their data from the same buffer. A particular input can have an offset for how its vertex data is accessed; this allows for interleaving vertex data.

[OpenGL 4.3/ARB_separate_attrib_format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Separate_Attribute_Format) provides [similar concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972230/734069) with `glVertexAttribFormat` and `glVertexAttribBinding`. The former specifies what attribute location the vertex data goes to. The latter specifies which buffer binding index will feed that attribute. Buffers are bound to buffer binding indices with `glBindVertexBuffer(s)`.

When using the older `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)/glVertexAttribPointer` APIs, the buffer binding index and the attribute location index are effectively the same. But this is a poor API and if you don't have to support older GL versions, I'd advise you to use the newer stuff.