# Could I change a vertex attribute's target vbo?

Tags: opengl

If I have to store data in different vbos, but the format of them are the same, how could I change the source vbo of a vertex attribute?

Comment: You have to bind the VAO and specify the attribute again by [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml).

Comment: So we can't set vbo by simple way?

Comment: Use the "modern" way of vertex attribute specification. See [glVertexAttribPointer and glVertexAttribFormat: What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972229/glvertexattribpointer-and-glvertexattribformat-whats-the-difference) respectively [Separate attribute format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format)