# question about the last parameter 'pointer' of 'glVertexAttribPointer' in learnOpenGL demo

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I read two demos about 'Getting started with OpenGL'

- Google Android [hello-gl2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/froyo-release/samples/hello-gl2)
  [gl_code.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/froyo-release/samples/hello-gl2/jni/gl_code.cpp)
- learnopengl.com [Hello-Triangle](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)
  [hello_triangle.cpp](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp)

For the last parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` :
google android demo : use array name `gTriangleVertices`
learnOpenGL.com demo : use `0`.

---

google android demo :

```
glUseProgram(gProgram);
checkGlError("glUseProgram");
glVertexAttribPointer(gvPositionHandle, 2, 
            GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 
            gTriangleVertices);       // array name
checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
```

learnOpenGL.com code segment :

```
// set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left  
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right 
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top   
}; 

unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
// bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, 
        GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
        3 * sizeof(float), 
        (void*)0);              // my question : `0` 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

// You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
// VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

click : [code comparision screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3cSB.png)

---

I tend to think that learnOpenGL's demo is wrong,
but learnOpenGL is a well-known website, it's impossible to make mistakes.
Finally , both demos can display triangle correctly.

I'm confused.

I'm confused about when to pass `0` and when to pass the `pointer value` ?

Comment: Instead of guessing why won't you just read what this argument means in [OpenGL documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)?

Comment: 0 is the default value of this argument and 0 is synonymous to "no pointer" in C/C++ languages

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I have read it. But i can get the key.

Comment: [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml): if a non-zero named buffer object is bound, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok, i'll follow.

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) has the type `const void *` for reasons of compatibility.

If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, the last argument (*pointer*) is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);
```

In legacy OpenGL (compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)) it is possible to specify a data pointer directly (in this case it must not be bound a buffer object, because the pointer should not be treated as a byte offset into the buffer):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), gTriangleVertices);
```

---

However, there is more. See [glVertexAttribPointer and glVertexAttribFormat: What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972229/glvertexattribpointer-and-glvertexattribformat-whats-the-difference?noredirect=1&lq=1)