# Draw multiple buffers with the same vertex layout

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I have multiple objects, each one of them has its own index buffer, vertex buffer, some have a different shader or texture, and all of them have the same vertex format (x, y, z, u, v, nx, ny, nz). I don't want to batch my objects together, but render them in separate draw calls. Lets say that I want to render 5 different objects (cubes, spheres, etc.), do I have to create a new vao for each one of them, or is there a way to tell OpenGL that I want to render 5 different buffers with the same layout/format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to tell OpenGL this; you simply modify the VAO and change the buffers without changing the vertex format.

Now granted, you can't do that without providing the vertex format parameters to `glVertexAttribPointer`. So at the very least, you have to remember what those parameters still are.

Fortunately, [separate attribute format exists (in GL 4.3+)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Separate_attribute_format), which allows you to change the buffer bindings (which are still stored in a VAO) [separately from the functions that change the vertex format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972230/734069). So you should just be able to call `glBindVertexBuffer` and `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` to change the buffers.

Comment: Just to know I understand what do you mean, I need to generate 1 VAO, n buffers, bind the VAO once and then before I render each object, I bind its buffer and link it to that bound VAO via glVertexAttribPointer(). So, if I render 5 objects, I call glVertexAttribPointer() 5 times. Is that what you've meant?